# Inconsistency in Amount due data in NetSuite API

Tags: rest, api, netsuite

I am trying to pull the Amount remaining data from Invoices in NetSuite.

The problem is the data is very inconsistent.

First of all, they do not provide the Amount remaining in the Invoice's currency. Looks like they only provide it in USD. So I tried to convert to the target currency with exchange rate and it works fine 75% of the time.

Conversion: Amount due in Foreign currency = Amount due in API reponse/exchange rate

SAMPLE RESPONSE 1:

```
{
Invoices: [
    {
        amountRemaining: 6096.9,
        currency: 2, <-- (GBP)
        exchangeRate: 1.354865,
        fxAmount: 4500,
        status: open,
        customFieldList: { },
        xmlns:platform_common: urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com,
        custom_segments: { },
        custom_fields: { }
    }
],
}
```

In sample 2, the exchange rate had to be around 1.3 but it is wrongly set as 0.76. However, the good thing is the Amount remaining is calculated according to the exchange rate and so the conversion with the above formula would still give me the correct amount due.

SAMPLE RESPONSE 2:

```
{
Invoices: [
    {
        amountRemaining: 58538.49,
        currency: 2, <-- (GBP)
        exchangeRate: 0.76009212,
        fxAmount: 77015,
        status: open,
        customFieldList: { },
        xmlns:platform_common: urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com,
        custom_segments: { },
        custom_fields: { }
    }
],
}
```

However, in sample 3, the exchange rate is wrongly set as 1. And the Amount due should have been 21523.32. However, it is around 30000. Not sure how this information is calculated.

SAMPLE RESPONSE 3:

```
{
Invoices: [
    {
        amountRemaining: 30132.648,
        currency: 2, <-- (GBP)
        exchangeRate: 1,
        fxAmount: 21523.32,
        status: open,
        customFieldList: { },
        xmlns:platform_common: urn:common_2017_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com,
        custom_segments: { },
        custom_fields: { }
    }
],
}
```

How is the Amount due calculated? Am I looking at the wrong fields for the conversion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your third example you have the field fxamount.

    fxAmount: 21523.32

It has the amount you are looking for, why not use that?

Comment: @RustyShackles In this case, that is the amount I am looking for. But its the total amount of the Invoice. Not the remaining balance. It is always going to be the same amount irrespective of how much has been paid off

Comment: There is a field called fxamountremaining have you tried using that?

Comment: @RustyShackles Looks like they do not expose that field in the API.

Comment: Where is the JSON reponse coming from? How is it created?  Is it a NetSuite RESTlet or Suitelet?  Do you have access to modify the JSON response?

Comment: @RustyShackles JSON response is from NetSuite. They have their out-of-the-box REST APIs. I do not have access to modify it.

Comment: That sucks cause that field is available as a search column.  If you were able to modiy the RESTlet, you should be able to return this value using a search.